# Firestore inquality error with where isNotEqual and orderBy

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to load users from firebase firestore where

- User uid is not the same as the logged-in user
- Order the result by timestamp

```dart
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> loadUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid)
        .orderBy('lastSent')
        .snapshots();
  }
```

But I'm getting an error

> The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([lastSent]), false]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([uid])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

> Failed assertion: line 677 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]'

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that what you're trying to do is not possible.  You can't have it sort by a field that's different than the field used in an inequality or range comparison operator.  Your inequality operator is using the field "uid", but your sort is using the field "lastSent".  This is a [documented limitation of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations).

If you want to sort the documents using a different field, you will have to perform that sort using code in your app (after the query is complete), not as part of the Firestore query.